# How do I protect sensitive information from cross site access?

Tags: cross-domain, security, access-control, cross-domain-policy

My web application displays some sensitive information to a logged in user. The user visits another site without explicitly logging out of my site first. How do I ensure that the other site can not access the sensitive information without accept from me or the user?

If for example my sensitive data is in JavaScript format, the other site can include it in a script tag and read the side effects. I could continue on building a blacklist, but I do not want to enumerate what is unsafe. I want to know what is safe, but I can not find any documentation of this.

UPDATE: In my example JavaScript from the *victim* site was executed on the *attacker's* site, not the other way around, which would have been Cross Site Scripting.

Another example is images, where any other site can read the width and height, but I don't think they can read the content, but they can display it.

A third example is that everything without an X-Frame-Options header can be loaded into an iframe, and from there it is possible to steal the data by tricking the user into doing drag-and-drop or copy-and-paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I did not get the answer I was looking for here, I asked in another forum an got the answer. It is here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mozilla.dev.security/9U6HTOh-p4g

I also found this page which answers my question:
http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2#Life_outside_same-origin_rules

Answer (score 1):

The key point of Cross Site Attack is to ensure that your input from user which is going to be displayed, is legal, not containing some scripts. You may stop it at the beginning.

Comment: No, I am not talking about input from users, or any untrusted data.

Answer (score 1):

> If for example my sensitive data is in JavaScript format, the other site can include it in a script tag

Yep! So don't put it in JavaScript/JSONP format.

The usual fix for passing back JSON or JS code is to put something unexecutable at the front to cause a syntax error or a hang (`for(;;);` is popular). So including the resource as a `<script>` doesn't get the attacker anywhere. When you access it from your own site you can fetch it with an XMLHttpRequest and chop off the prefix before evaluating it.

(A workaround that doesn't work is checking `window.location` in the returned script: when you're being included in an attacker's page they have control of the JavaScript environment and could sabotage the built-in objects to do unexpected things.)

Comment: Yes, JavaScript/JSONP is an example of what I **can not** do. I also know other examples. What I want to know is what I **can** do. You say that JSON is safe, but is it only protected against embedding using a `<script>` tag, or is is protected against all forms of embedding? And is anything else safe, or is only JSON safe? I guess HTML is also safe?

Answer (score 0):

First of all like superpdm states, design your app from the ground up to ensure that either the sensitive information is not stored on the client side in the first place or that it is unintelligible to a malicious users.

Additionally, for items of data you don't have much control over, you can take advantage of inbuilt HTTP controls like [HttpOnly](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTPOnly) that tries to ensure that client-side scripts will not have access to cookies like your session token and so forth. Setting `httpOnly` on your cookies will go a long way to ensure malicious vbscripts, javascripts etc will not read or modify your client-side tokens.

Comment: While `HttpOnly` is nice, it won't help when my sensitive data is something my authenticated user has to see, since the user won't see the cookie. Not sending the information to the client at all is not an option, since the whole point of my application is to show this information to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I think some confusion is still in our web-security knowledge world. You are afraid of **Cross Site Request Forgery**, and yet describing and looking for solution to **Cross Site Scripting**.

**Cross Site Scripting** is a vulnerability that allows malicious person to inject some unwanted content into your site. It may be some text, but it also may be some JS code or VB or Java Applet (I mentioned applets because they can be used to circumvent protection provided by the `httpOnly` flag). And thus if your aware user clicks on the malicious link he may get his data stolen. It depends on amount of sensitive data presented to the user. Clicking on a link is not only attack vector for XSS attack, If you present to users unfiltered contents provided by other users, someone may also inject some evil code and do some damage. He does not need to steal someone's cookie to get what he wants. And it has notnig to do with visiting other site while still being logged to your app.  I recommend:[XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

**Cross Site Request Forgery** is a vulnerability that allows someone to construct specially crafted form and present it to Logged in user, user after submitting this form may execute operation in your app that he didin't intended. Operation may be transfer, password change, or user add. And this is the threat you are worried about, if  user holds session with your app and visits site with such form which gets auto-submited with JS such request gets authenticated, and operation executed. And httpOnly will not protect from it because attacker does not need to access sessionId stored in cookies. I recommend: [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/CSRF)

Comment: You are right in that my question is not related to XSS. Note that I said my script was included on the attacker's site, not the other way around. My question is somewhat related to CSRF, but it is not quite the same. CSRF is about a third party site performing a sensitive action on behalf of the user. My question is about a third party site reading sensitive information on behalf of the user. For example, to prevent CSRF, I have to check a CSRF-token. But how do I prevent the attacker from reading the CSRF-token in the first place?